# SQL Server Create trigger: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, triggers

I am trying to convert a db2 trigger in SQL Server. I have already changed some things as the NEWDOC and OLDDOC references and removed 'THEN' keywords.

I am still getting this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
```

the SQL is:

```
-- <ScriptOptions statementTerminator="!" />
CREATE TRIGGER DOCUMENTS_UPDATE ON DOCUMENTS_VIEW
INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
  IF (select user_id from inserted) is null
    UPDATE DOCUMENTS 
    SET    id = (select id from inserted), 
           user_id = (SELECT id from users 
                      where username = (select username from inserted)
                     ), 
           code = (select code from inserted), 
           description = (select description from inserted), 
           type = (select type from inserted), 
           expiry = (select expiry from inserted), 
           parent_code = (select parent_code from inserted), 
           attributes = (select attributes from inserted), 
           acquired = (select acquired from inserted) 
    WHERE id = (select id from inserted);
  ELSE 
    UPDATE DOCUMENTS 
    SET    id = (select id from inserted), 
           user_id = (select user_id from inserted), 
           code = (select code from inserted), 
           description = (select description from inserted), 
           type = (select type from inserted), 
           expiry = (select expiry from inserted), 
           parent_code = (select parent_code from inserted), 
           attributes = (select attributes from inserted), 
           acquired = (select acquired from inserted) 
    WHERE id = (select id from inserted);
  END IF;

  UPDATE DOCUMENT_STATES 
  SET    document_id = (select id from inserted), 
         state = (select state from inserted), 
         date = (select date from inserted), 
         timestamp = (select timestamp from inserted) 
  WHERE document_id = (select id from inserted);

  IF NEWDOC.type = 'client_order' 
    UPDATE DOCUMENTS 
    SET    parent_code = (select code from inserted) 
    WHERE code = (select parent_code from inserted);
END IF;
END!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax problem is easy to fix.  As GandRalph points out, there is no `END IF` in SQL Server.

More importantly, you are not using `inserted` correctly.  It can contain more than one row -- all rows affected by the DML statement.  Your query will fail spectacularly with errors when that happens.

The first `if` can be replaced by a single `update`.  It would look like this:

```
update d
    set  user_id = coalesce(u.id, i.userid),
         code = i.code, 
         description = i.description, 
         type = i.type, 
         expiry = i.expiry, 
         parent_code = i.parent_code, 
         attributes = i.attributes, 
         acquired = i.acquired 
    from documents d join
         inserted i
         on d.id = i.id left join
         users u
         on u.username = i.username
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no END IF in TSQL.  Format should be:

```
IF <condition>
Begin
 --Do something
End
Else
Begin
 --Do something
End
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
DOCUMENTS_UPDATE ON DOCUMENTS_VIEW
INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (select user_id from inserted) is null
        UPDATE DOCUMENTS SET id = (select id from inserted), user_id = (SELECT id 
        from users where username =(select username from inserted)), code = (select 
        code from inserted), description = (select description from inserted), type 
        = (select type from inserted), 
        expiry = (select expiry from inserted), parent_code = (select parent_code 
        from inserted), attributes=(select attributes from inserted), acquired=
        (select acquired from inserted) WHERE id = (select id from inserted);
    ELSE 
        UPDATE DOCUMENTS SET id = (select id from inserted), user_id = (select 
        user_id from inserted), code = (select code from inserted), description = 
        (select description from inserted), type = (select type from inserted), 
        expiry = (select expiry from inserted), parent_code = (select parent_code 
        from inserted), attributes=(select attributes from inserted), acquired=
        (select acquired from inserted) WHERE id = (select id from inserted);

    UPDATE DOCUMENT_STATES SET document_id =(select id from inserted), state = 
    (select state from inserted), date = (select date from inserted), timestamp 
     =  (select timestamp from inserted) WHERE document_id = (select id from 
    inserted);

    IF NEWDOC.type = 'client_order'
        UPDATE DOCUMENTS SET parent_code = (select code from inserted) WHERE code = 
        (select parent_code from inserted);

END
```